# WampServer 2.5 Offline

Tags: aplicação-web, wamp

Estou com um problema no WampServer 2.5 (Windows 8.1).
Houve a necessidade de eu alterar uma configuração no apache (httpd.conf), para permitir e aceitar  rewrite module. Depois de feito a alteração nas linhas:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

para

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

e `AllowOverride None` para `AllowOverride All`
Meu server parou de rodar. Fica na cor laranja (offline).

Como em outros momentos/oportunidades já havia presenciados problemas deste categoria relacionado aos conflitos de porta do WAMP com os outros programas instalados em maquinas. Resolvi alterar a porta do WAMP (2 tentativas uma para a porta 82 e a outra para  8080), porém não obtive sucesso e o serviço continua offline.

Vou detalhar abaixo os passos realizados na operação:

No arquivo httpd.conf além das alterações já citada.
Substituí

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80 por #Listen 12.34.56.78:8080
Listen 0.0.0.0:80      por Listen 0.0.0.0:8080
Listen [::0]:80        por Listen [::0]:8080
```

e servername para localhost:8080

No arquivo `wampmanager.tpl`

de `w_testPort80` para `w_testPort8080` em todos as linhas.
e os parametros http://localhost:80/webgrind(exemplo)/  http://localhost:8080/webgrind(exemplo)/

Arquivo TestPort onde mencionava 80 para 8080

E por fim no arquivo  `english.lang`

```
$w_testPort8080 = 'Test Port 8080';
```

Alguém já teve problema parecido?

PS: Já reiniciei a máquina, finalizei o demais programas e nada. Até já alterei na configuração quando ainda funcionava, porém ainda nada.

Comment: Seria interessante ver o error_log do seu Apache.

Comment: Eu havia dado uma olhada ele só aponta os erros de acesso msm. Agora o Wamp continua laranja porém no hint (dica) dele mostra ONLINE. Tento subir o servidor e apresenta a página de erro.

Comment: Eu estava com o mesmo problema. Fiz o seguinte: Deixei APENAS o `localhost` na porta `8080` e os outros eu deixei na porta `80`. No ícone ao lado do relógio fui em `Apache`, `Services`, `Install Service` e funcionou.